# tf.keras.predict() is much slower than Keras predict()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

When using the Keras that comes embedded with Tensorflow (Tensorflow 2), I noticed a severe increase in computational time when using the `predict()` function from the Keras embedded inside Tensorflow and the `predict()` from standalone Keras. See the toy code below:

```
import tensorflow
import keras
import numpy as np
import time

test = np.array([[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0., 0.1, 0.2]])

# Keras from inside Tensorflow
model_1 = tensorflow.keras.Sequential([
  tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu', input_shape=(10,)),
])

start_1 = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
    result = model_1.predict(test)
elapsed_time_1 = time.time() - start_1

# Standalone Keras
model_2 = keras.models.Sequential([
  keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu', input_shape=(10,)),
]) 

start_2 = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
    result = model_2.predict(test)
elapsed_time_2 = time.time() - start_2

print(elapsed_time_1)
print(elapsed_time_2)
```

The output from the code below in my machine is

```
17.82757878303528
0.31248927116394043
```

The expected output is that the `predict()` from `tensorflow.keras` should take the same amount of time for the same task, when compared to the `predict()` from standalone Keras.

My questions are:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I fix this?

My specs:

> Python version: Python 3.6.8
>
> Keras version: 2.3.1
>
> Tensorflow version: 2.1.0
>
> Running on Windows 10

Comment: I think this is a problem (most likely a bug) with TensorFlow 2.0, if you use TensorFlow 1.x  there are no performance differences.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Such a shame. Do you know of any alternatives to avoid this performance issue? I really would like to use the embedded Keras with TF 2.0 (as Keras themselves advises) but my original problem depends heavily on multiple predict() calls.

Comment: Run `model.predict()` twice  is the same script and see the times of the second run.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal If I understood what you asked correctly, when using `tf.keras.predict()` looped twice in a row the times I get are `22.3723361492157s` and `21.57545781135559s` whereas when doing the same test but using a Keras model I get `0.31824159622192383s` and `0.30228185653686523s`.

Comment: The model object is created outside the loop? I mean is the basic structure similar to `model = create_model()` followed by 'measure_time(model.predict()) for i in range(2)`

Comment: Also, are you using `model.compile()`, or calling the model directly (i.e., just `model(inputs)` anytime before `model.predict()`?

Comment: Isn't the code I provided replicating the problem for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mostly due to eager execution. You can turn off eager execution with

```
tensorflow.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

Doing that, the tf.keras is still ~2x slower, which I'm not sure why, but not by orders of magnitude. Both of them go even faster if you convert to tensors beforehand.